# Wordpress functions.php not loading js and css files

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

So I wrote the following code into my functions.php file:

```
function buena_child_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('extra js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/extra.js');

    wp_enqueue_script('test js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/test.js');
    wp_enqueue_style('custom css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'buena_child_scripts');
```

The css and js files just don't get loaded.

Of course I have `<?php wp_head(); ?>` inside my index.php

And I can manually call the js and css and that works...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does console/firebug say?

Comment: also, you can try `get_template_directory_uri()` as well

Comment: `get_template_directory_uri()` isn't working either and the console is blank.

Comment: Been a long time since I've done WP, so I'm just tossing ideas here, but you can also try to use wp_enqueue_script() and wp_enqueue_style() respectively, and see if that works? Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts

Comment: Does not work... It works for everyone but me <.<

Answer (score 0):

I think your spaces are the problem. Add dashes for separation like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('test-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/test.js');
```

**Edit:** I more often use the get_bloginfo method–could you try this out and see if it works for you?

```
function buena_child_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'extra-js', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/extra.js');
  wp_enqueue_script( 'test-js', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/test.js');

  wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-css', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/css/custom.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'buena_child_scripts');
```

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script('test-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/test.js');`
`wp_enqueue_style('custom-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css');`

Not working

Comment: No, using the wp_enqueue_script() and such, the code would be `wp_enqueue_script('test.js','test.js',false)`

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie no, the first parameter is for naming the script; your code just repeats the filename itself. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: @Lostflash I edited my answer and I'm curious if this method works for you?

Comment: bezierer: yes, I know that - although I could've written test-js in the first option, that doesn't really matter.

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script( 'test-js', get_bloginfo( '/js/test.js' ) . '/js/test.js');
 wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-css', get_bloginfo( '/css/custom.css' ) . '/css/custom.css');` If that is right, then it does not work for me.

Comment: No–what you just posted isn't what I wrote, you should have this: wp_enqueue_script( 'test-js', get_bloginfo( '/js/test.js' ) . '/js/test.js'); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-css', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/css/custom.css');

Comment: Also not working. I don't have an header.php file because I wrote the wp_head() in the index.php. Is that even right?

Comment: That sounds odd–wp_head() should go in header.php before the closing </head> tag. index.php is just a page template like front-page.php or single.php and should include stuff like the header. This may be what's causing you so much grief.

Comment: Even after adding it still the same :( I even watched some videos and read so many forum post and did all they did but it's not working.